# Explain the code beow

Tags: android, listview

I am learning how to use a Listview in android development. The example uses the list of contacts on the user's phone. There is this code, I cant figure it out. Any help will be appreciated.

```
static final String SELECTION = "((" + 
        ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " NOTNULL) AND (" +
        ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " != '' ))";
```

I can't figure out what it is doing. Tutorial is from [android.dev.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)
Thank you

Comment: looks like you are selecting everything that has a not null, and not empty display name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That tutorial is using a CursorLoader to dinamically retrieve the data from a database and use it to fill the views in list view.

That string is the search criteria... It tells to cursorloader which content it must retrieve from the database.